# Reduce The Lengthly Code In Firemonkey

Tags: firemonkey

I have many layouts in my Firemonkey APP, and all the TVertscrollBox share the same DoCalcContentsBounds, DoRestorePosition, DoUpdateKBBounds as below, I want to reduce it and keep the same functionality, how can I do?

```
    procedure TBTCXCHGForm.BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
begin
  if BTCXCHGAddSalesVertScrollBox.Visible then
  begin
    with BTCXCHGAddSalesVertScrollBox do
      ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
  end
  else
  begin
    if BTCXCHGEnterSellerDetailVertScrollBox.Visible then
    begin
      with BTCXCHGEnterSellerDetailVertScrollBox do
        ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
    end
    else
    begin
      if BTCXCHGEnterBuyBTCDetailVertScrollBox.Visible then
      begin
        with BTCXCHGEnterBuyBTCDetailVertScrollBox do
          ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
      end
      else
      begin
        if BTCXCHGAddBuyVertScrollBox.Visible then
        begin
          with BTCXCHGAddBuyVertScrollBox do
            ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
        end
        else
        begin
          if BTCXCHGChangeSalesConfirmationVertScrollBox.Visible then
          begin
            with BTCXCHGChangeSalesConfirmationVertScrollBox do
              ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
          end
          else
          begin
            if BTCXCHGEnterSellBTCDetailVertScrollBox.Visible then
            begin
              with BTCXCHGEnterSellBTCDetailVertScrollBox do
                ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
            end
            else
            begin
              if BTCXCHGMinerPurchaseVertScrollBox.Visible then
              begin
                with BTCXCHGMinerPurchaseVertScrollBox do
                  ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
              end
              else
              begin
                if BTCXCHGReceiveBitcoinsVertScrollBox.Visible then
                begin
                  with BTCXCHGReceiveBitcoinsVertScrollBox do
                    ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                end
                else
                begin
                  if BTCXCHGSendBitcoinsVertScrollBox.Visible then
                  begin
                    with BTCXCHGSendBitcoinsVertScrollBox do
                      ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                  end
                  else
                  begin
                    if BTCXCHGUserRegistrationVertScrollBox.Visible then
                    begin
                      with BTCXCHGUserRegistrationVertScrollBox do
                        ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                      if BTCXCHGChangeSecurityPasswordVertScrollBox.Visible then
                      begin
                        with BTCXCHGChangeSecurityPasswordVertScrollBox do
                          ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                      end
                      else
                      begin
                        if BTCXCHGChangeUserPasswordVertScrollBox.Visible then
                        begin
                          with BTCXCHGChangeUserPasswordVertScrollBox do
                            ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                          if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserEmailVerificationVertScrollBox.Visible then
                          begin
                            with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserEmailVerificationVertScrollBox do
                              ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                          end
                          else
                          begin
                            if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserForgetPasswordVertScrollBox.Visible then
                            begin
                              with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserForgetPasswordVertScrollBox do
                                ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                              if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserLoginVertScrollBox.Visible then
                              begin
                                with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserLoginVertScrollBox do
                                  ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                              end
                              else
                              begin
                                if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionRegistrationVertScrollBox.Visible then
                                begin
                                  with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionRegistrationVertScrollBox do
                                    ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
                                end;
                              end;
                            end;
                          end;
                        end;
                      end;
                    end;
                  end;
                end;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TBTCXCHGForm.BTCXCHGDoUpdateKBBounds;
var
  LFocused: TControl;
  LFocusRect: TRectF;
begin
  if BTCXCHGAddSalesVertScrollBox.Visible then
  begin
      BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

      if Assigned(Focused) then
      begin
        LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
        LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
        LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGAddSalesVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

        if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
        begin
          BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
          BTCXCHGAddSalesLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
          with BTCXCHGAddSalesVertScrollBox do
          begin
            RealignContent;
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
          end;
        end;
      end;

      if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
        BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
  end
  else
  begin
    if BTCXCHGEnterSellerDetailVertScrollBox.Visible then
    begin
      BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

      if Assigned(Focused) then
      begin
        LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
        LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
        LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGEnterSellerDetailVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

        if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
        begin
          BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
          BTCXCHGEnterSellerDetailLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
          with BTCXCHGEnterSellerDetailVertScrollBox do
          begin
            RealignContent;
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
          end;
        end;
      end;

      if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
        BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
    end
    else
    begin
      if BTCXCHGEnterBuyBTCDetailVertScrollBox.Visible then
      begin
        BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

        if Assigned(Focused) then
        begin
          LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
          LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
          LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGEnterBuyBTCDetailVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

          if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
          begin
            BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
            BTCXCHGEnterBuyBTCDetailLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
            with BTCXCHGEnterBuyBTCDetailVertScrollBox do
            begin
              RealignContent;
              Application.ProcessMessages;
              ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
            end;
          end;
        end;

        if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
          BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
      end
      else
      begin
        if BTCXCHGAddBuyVertScrollBox.Visible then
        begin
          BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

          if Assigned(Focused) then
          begin
            LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
            LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
            LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGAddBuyVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

            if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
            begin
              BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
              BTCXCHGAddBuyLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
              with BTCXCHGAddBuyVertScrollBox do
              begin
                RealignContent;
                Application.ProcessMessages;
                ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
              end;
            end;
          end;

          if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
            BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
        end
        else
        begin
          if BTCXCHGChangeSalesConfirmationVertScrollBox.Visible then
          begin
            BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

            if Assigned(Focused) then
            begin
              LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
              LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
              LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGChangeSalesConfirmationVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

              if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
              begin
                BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                BTCXCHGChangeSalesConfirmationLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                with BTCXCHGChangeSalesConfirmationVertScrollBox do
                begin
                  RealignContent;
                  Application.ProcessMessages;
                  ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                end;
              end;
            end;

            if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
              BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
          end
          else
          begin
            if BTCXCHGEnterSellBTCDetailVertScrollBox.Visible then
            begin
              BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

              if Assigned(Focused) then
              begin
                LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGEnterSellBTCDetailVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                begin
                  BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                  BTCXCHGEnterSellBTCDetailLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                  with BTCXCHGEnterSellBTCDetailVertScrollBox do
                  begin
                    RealignContent;
                    Application.ProcessMessages;
                    ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                  end;
                end;
              end;

              if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
            end
            else
            begin
              if BTCXCHGMinerPurchaseVertScrollBox.Visible then
              begin
                BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                if Assigned(Focused) then
                begin
                  LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                  LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                  LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGMinerPurchaseVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                  if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                  begin
                    BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                    BTCXCHGMinerPurchaseLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                    with BTCXCHGMinerPurchaseVertScrollBox do
                    begin
                      RealignContent;
                      Application.ProcessMessages;
                      ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                    end;
                  end;
                end;

                if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                  BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
              end
              else
              begin
                if BTCXCHGReceiveBitcoinsVertScrollBox.Visible then
                begin
                  BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                  if Assigned(Focused) then
                  begin
                    LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                    LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                    LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGReceiveBitcoinsVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                    if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                    begin
                      BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                      BTCXCHGReceiveBitcoinsLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                      with BTCXCHGReceiveBitcoinsVertScrollBox do
                      begin
                        RealignContent;
                        Application.ProcessMessages;
                        ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                      end;
                    end;
                  end;

                  if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                    BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                end
                else
                begin
                  if BTCXCHGSendBitcoinsVertScrollBox.Visible then
                  begin
                    BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                    if Assigned(Focused) then
                    begin
                      LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                      LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                      LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGSendBitcoinsVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                      if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                      begin
                        BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                        BTCXCHGSendBitcoinsLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                        with BTCXCHGSendBitcoinsVertScrollBox do
                        begin
                          RealignContent;
                          Application.ProcessMessages;
                          ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                        end;
                      end;
                    end;

                    if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                      BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                  end
                  else
                  begin
                    if BTCXCHGUserRegistrationVertScrollBox.Visible then
                    begin
                      BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                      if Assigned(Focused) then
                      begin
                        LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                        LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                        LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGUserRegistrationVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                        if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                        begin
                          BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                          BTCXCHGUserRegistrationLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                          with BTCXCHGUserRegistrationVertScrollBox do
                          begin
                            RealignContent;
                            Application.ProcessMessages;
                            ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                          end;
                        end;
                      end;

                      if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                        BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                      if BTCXCHGChangeSecurityPasswordVertScrollBox.Visible then
                      begin
                        BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                        if Assigned(Focused) then
                        begin
                          LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                          LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                          LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGChangeSecurityPasswordVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                          if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                          begin
                            BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                            BTCXCHGChangeSecurityPasswordLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                            with BTCXCHGChangeSecurityPasswordVertScrollBox do
                            begin
                              RealignContent;
                              Application.ProcessMessages;
                              ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                            end;
                          end;
                        end;

                        if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                          BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                      end
                      else
                      begin
                        if BTCXCHGChangeUserPasswordVertScrollBox.Visible then
                        begin
                          BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                          if Assigned(Focused) then
                          begin
                            LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                            LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                            LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGChangeUserPasswordVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                            if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                            begin
                              BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                              BTCXCHGChangeUserPasswordLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                              with BTCXCHGChangeUserPasswordVertScrollBox do
                              begin
                                RealignContent;
                                Application.ProcessMessages;
                                ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                              end;
                            end;
                          end;

                          if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                            BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                          if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserEmailVerificationVertScrollBox.Visible then
                          begin
                            BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                            if Assigned(Focused) then
                            begin
                              LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                              LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                              LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserEmailVerificationVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                              if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                              begin
                                BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                                BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserEmailVerificationLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                                with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserEmailVerificationVertScrollBox do
                                begin
                                  RealignContent;
                                  Application.ProcessMessages;
                                  ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                                end;
                              end;
                            end;

                            if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                              BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                          end
                          else
                          begin
                            if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserForgetPasswordVertScrollBox.Visible then
                            begin
                              BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                              if Assigned(Focused) then
                              begin
                                LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                                LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                                LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserForgetPasswordVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                                if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                                begin
                                  BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                                  BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserForgetPasswordLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                                  with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserForgetPasswordVertScrollBox do
                                  begin
                                    RealignContent;
                                    Application.ProcessMessages;
                                    ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                                  end;
                                end;
                              end;

                              if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                                BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                            end
                            else
                            begin
                              if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserLoginVertScrollBox.Visible then
                              begin
                                BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                                if Assigned(Focused) then
                                begin
                                  LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                                  LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                                  LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserLoginVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                                  if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                                  begin
                                    BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                                    BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserLoginLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                                    with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionUserLoginVertScrollBox do
                                    begin
                                      RealignContent;
                                      Application.ProcessMessages;
                                      ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                                    end;
                                  end;
                                end;

                                if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                                  BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                              end
                              else
                              begin
                                if BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionRegistrationVertScrollBox.Visible then
                                begin
                                  BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

                                  if Assigned(Focused) then
                                  begin
                                    LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
                                    LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
                                    LFocusRect.Offset(BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionRegistrationVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);

                                    if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
                                    begin
                                      BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
                                      BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionRegistrationLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
                                      with BTCXCHGLoginRegisterSelectionRegistrationVertScrollBox do
                                      begin
                                        RealignContent;
                                        Application.ProcessMessages;
                                        ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
                                      end;
                                    end;
                                  end;

                                  if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
                                    BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
                                end;
                              end;
                            end;
                          end;
                        end;
                      end;
                    end;
                  end;
                end;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: OK, first of all get rid of those with statements, they are cancer. Then look at your code again, identify repetitions and extract methods from that. Just look at yout code and try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a field in `TBTCXCHGForm` to hold a reference to currently visible VertScrollBox. Whenever the visible VertScrollBox is changed, assign the scroll box to this field. For example:

```
CurrentlyVisibleVertScrollBox: TVertscrollBox;
```

Then your `BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition` procedure can be reduced to

```
procedure TBTCXCHGForm.BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
begin
  with CurrentlyVisibleVertScrollBox do  // <----
    ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, 0);
end;
```

and the `BTCXCHGDoUpdateKBBounds` can be reduced to

```
procedure TBTCXCHGForm.BTCXCHGDoUpdateKBBounds;
var
  LFocused: TControl;
  LFocusRect: TRectF;
begin
  BTCXCHGNeedOffset := False;

  if Assigned(Focused) then
  begin
    LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
    LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
    LFocusRect.Offset(CurrentlyVisibleVertScrollBox.ViewportPosition);  // <----

    if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(BTCXCHGKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top) then
    begin
      BTCXCHGNeedOffset := True;
      BTCXCHGAddSalesLayout.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
      with CurrentlyVisibleVertScrollBox do  // <----
      begin
        RealignContent;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        ViewportPosition := PointF(ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - BTCXCHGKBBounds.Top);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if not BTCXCHGNeedOffset then
    BTCXCHGDoRestorePosition;
end;
```

The modified lines are marked (  // <----).
You did not post the third procedure, `DoCalcContentsBounds`, but if it follows a similar pattern, it should be obvious how to modify it.